# Dynamic Adding/Creating Selectpicker on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-selectpicker

I would like to dynamically add a row in my HTML table on click of an add button. The row contains a select element which uses the **selectpicker class**. When I remove the selectpicker class in my script to add a new row, the select element perfectly appears in the newly created row. But when I use the selectpicker in the script, the element does not render.

This is my table:

```js
$(".addRow").click(function() {
      $(this).closest('table').find('tr:last').prev().after('<tr><td> <
        select name = "myselect[]"
        id = "myselect"
        class = "selectpicker" >
        <
        option > --Select Resp.Center-- < /option> <
        option value = "1" > My Option 1 < /option> <
        option value = "2" > My Option 2 < /option> <
        option value = "3" > My Option 3 < /option> <
        /select> <
        /td> <
        td >
        <
        a href = "#"
        class = "removeRow" > < i class = "fa fa-minus-square fa-fw" > < /i></a >
        <
        /td> <
        /tr>');
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="myRow">
    <td>
      <select name="myselect[]" id="myselect" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
        <option>--Select Option--</option>
        <option value="1">My Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">My Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">My Option 3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><a href="#" class="addRow"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Solved this already. Just made the bootstrap-select.js load last.

Answer (score 0):

Strings can't have linebreaks in them. Just remove the linebreaks and it renders fine.

```
$(".addRow").click(function (elem) {
    $(this).closest('table').find("tr:last").after('<tr><td><select name="myselect[]" id="myselect" class="selectpicker"><option>--Select Resp. Center--</option><option value="1">My Option 1</option><option value="2">My Option 2</option><option value="3">My Option 3</option></select></td><td><a href="#" class="removeRow"><i class="fa fa-minus-square fa-fw"></i></a></td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But i just used line breaks in the code above for easier reading. I do not have line breaks in my code, and it does not still render.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your selector, also you need to concatenate the select options.

```js
$(".addRow").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('table').find('tr:last').after('<tr><td> ' +
    '<select name="myselect[]" id="myselect" class="selectpicker">' +
    '   <option>--Select Resp. Center--</option>' +
    '  <option value="1">My Option 1</option>' +
    ' <option value="2">My Option 2</option>' +
    '<option value="3">My Option 3</option>' +
    '</select>' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td>' +
    '   <a href="#" class="removeRow"><i class="fa fa-minus-square fa-fw"></i></a>' +
    '</td>' +
    ' </tr>');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="myRow">
    <td>
      <select name="myselect[]" id="myselect" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
        <option>--Select Option--</option>
        <option value="1">My Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">My Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">My Option 3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><a href="#" class="addRow"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm fully aware of the proper concatenation. I just used line breaks above for easier reading. I do not have linebreaks in my codes, but still the select element does not render.

Comment: Have you tried the code above? What does the error says, if there is?

Comment: There are no errors.. Anyway, I used the selector because I wanted to add row before the last row of my table.. Removing the prev() in the selector adds new rows at the end of the table, still the select does not render..

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by placing the bootstrap-select.js (for selectpicker) after all js files in my php file to make it load last.